# How do I create a Y (year only) datetime field in Drupal 8?

Tags: datetime, drupal-8, granularity

***Datetime module, Drupal 8:*** **I want to create a datetime field with year granularity.** In *Drupal 7*, it was no problem. Now in *Drupal 8*, it isn't possible anymore. How can I create such a field without the ***Years Only*** module since it isn't safe? Can I write a theme function? If so, how do I do that?

Excerpt from the datetime.module:

/** * Defines the format that date and time should be stored in. */

**const DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s';**

/** * Defines the format that dates should be stored in. */

**const DATETIME_DATE_STORAGE_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d';**

Answer (score 2):

This module is used to collect year part of date in any field. It provides a custom field type Year Only in the field UI.

With the help of this module one can add field where he/she wants to get year only instead of complete date.

https://www.drupal.org/project/yearonly

Latest release on 24 October 2017, right after 2 days you post this question. So, it's not cover by Drupal.

Hope it's help